# android + google map API v2 errors

Tags: android, google-maps, compiler-errors

i am trying to install 2 packages for the using of the google map on the emulator  but i get a problem in the log cat and i do not know how to fix this error on the emulator it display  **this app wont  run unless you  update  the google play services**  can anyone help me ??? 
these are the files and the code that i used to build the simple

## mainActivity.java

```
package com.example.googlemapv2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

## main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

## manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemapv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.googlemapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API KEY" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemapv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

## LOG CAT

```
04-12 09:27:58.548: E/Trace(622): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-12 09:27:59.448: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(622): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-12 09:27:59.468: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(622): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-12 09:27:59.498: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(622): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-12 09:27:59.510: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(622): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-12 09:27:59.537: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(622): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-12 09:27:59.578: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(622): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-12 09:27:59.888: D/gralloc_goldfish(622): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-12 09:28:13.158: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(622): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
04-12 09:37:16.108: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(622): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
04-12 09:37:16.108: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(622):   in com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@414a00c0
04-12 09:37:16.108: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(622):   0: sent at 692046000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=692046, downTime=691902, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
04-12 09:37:16.108: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(622):   -- recent events --
04-12 09:37:16.108: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(622):   1: sent at 222169403000, (unhandled) MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=464.0, y[0]=562.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=222169, downTime=222095, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
04-12 09:37:16.108: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(622):   2: sent at 222095935000, (unhandled) MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=464.0, y[0]=562.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=222095, downTime=222095, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
04-12 09:37:16.108: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(622):   3: sent at 146103826000, MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=111.0, y[0]=287.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=146103, downTime=146009, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
04-12 09:37:16.108: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(622):   4: sent at 146009274000, MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=111.0, y[0]=287.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=146009, downTime=146009, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
04-12 09:37:16.208: D/dalvikvm(622): GC_CONCURRENT freed 257K, 3% free 10934K/11271K, paused 22ms+10ms, total 144ms
```

Comment: Hi there. I notice that you have four other similarly-named questions that you've asked in the last few days. I accept that these are not duplicates of each other, but it seems to me that you would benefit greatly from getting a book on Android development and trying to master some basics - I genuinely think development of a real app will be faster for you that way. Also, where you get an error message, try searching for it, since it is likely to have been tackled by someone on the Internet before.